# .htaccess redirect loop and regex issues

Tags: .htaccess

I have a simple htaccess redirect to send visitors from website.com/promotions to website.com/go/promotions. If I use the code below I get a redirect loop error:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URL} !^go$
RewriteRule promotion/index.html go/promotion/index.html [R,L,NC]
```

The RewriteCond is supposed to prevent the loop by not redirecting if the request url contains "go" but it doesn't appear to be working.

In addition I'm trying to set up a regex so that promotion/anypage.html will be redirected to go/promotion/anypage.html. I tried the following code but it wouldn't match anything:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^go$
RewriteRule ^promotion/(.*)$   go/promotion/$1   [R,L,NC]
```

Does anybody have an clues as to why either of these blocks isn't working properly ?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%{REQUEST_URL}` isn't a var you can match against, you're probably thinking of `%{REQUEST_URI}`, but it starts with a leading slash so `^go` will never match anything.

You just need a single rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?promotion/(.*)$ /go/promotion/$1 [R,L]
```

Or you can use mod_alias:

```
Redirect /promotion/ /go/promotion/
```

Comment: Excellent. That's got it. Looks like I was close with my second rule, I was just missing the forward slashes at the start of the statements.

Answer (score 1):

You're checking if the entire URL is just "go" on it's own, which it's not:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?go/
RewriteRule promotion/index.html go/promotion/index.html [R,L,NC]
```